# opencvで2値化し、特定の座標を表示させたいです

Tags: c++, opencv, kinect

以下のエラーが消えません！

- cv::MAT h_image 式にはポインタ型が必要です

os windows10
コンパイラ　visual studio2017

よろしくお願い致します。
引用元：
https://detail.chiebukuro.yahoo.co.jp/qa/question_detail/q1292659747
http://kivantium.hateblo.jp/entry/20120822/p1
Kinect 実践プログラム　杉浦司

```c
#include"stdafx.h"
#include <Windows.h>
#include <NuiApi.h>

#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
            while (1) {
                drawRgbImage(image);

            cv::Mat h_image;
            cv::flip(image, h_image, 1);

            // RGB画像をHSV画像に変換
            cv::Mat hsv, extracted;
            cv::cvtColor(h_image, hsv, CV_RGB2HSV); // カメラ画像がBGRの場合はCV_BGR2HSV
                                                    // 色が100<=H<=120, 80<=S<=255, 80<=V<=255の範囲の部分を抽出する
                                                    // 色の範囲は抽出したい物体の色に合わせて調整する
            cv::Scalar hsv_min = cv::Scalar(120, 80, 80);
            cv::Scalar hsv_max = cv::Scalar(130, 255, 255);
            cv::inRange(hsv, hsv_min, hsv_max, extracted);

            // ラベリング実行
            cv::Mat labelImg, stats, centroids;
            int nLabels = cv::connectedComponentsWithStats(extracted, labelImg, stats, centroids);

            //画像を表示する
            cv::imshow("kinect Sample", h_image);

            //白く塗りつぶし
            using namespace std;

            //入力ファイル、出力ファイル名
            const char* srcimgfname("g:\\testimg\\test.bmp");
            const char* rstimgfname("g:\\testimg\\result.bmp");

            IplImage *srcimg = cvLoadImage(srcimgfname, CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
            //入力画像をコピーし、白く塗りつぶす
            IplImage *rstimg = cvCloneImage(srcimg);

                cvRectangle(srcimg, cvPoint(0, 0),
                    cvPoint(h_image->width, srcimg->height),
                    CV_RGB(0xff, 0xff, 0xff), CV_FILLED);

                //画像データへのポインタ
                unsigned char *srcpt = (unsigned char *)srcimg->imageData; //入力画像
                unsigned char *rstpt = (unsigned char *)rstimg->imageData; //出力画像

                for (int y = 0; y < srcimg->height; ++y) {
                    for (int x = 0; x < srcimg->width; ++x) {
                        if ((srcpt[0] == 0x00) && //B
                            (srcpt[1] == 0x00) && //G 
                            (srcpt[2] == 0xff)) { //R
                                                  //半径3の赤い円を描き、座標値を出力
                            cvCircle(rstimg, cvPoint(x, y), 3, CV_RGB(0xff, 0, 0));
                            printf("(%d,%d)=\n", x, y);
                        }
                //ポインタを次の画素へ進める
                        srcpt += srcimg->nChannels;
                        rstpt += rstimg->nChannels;
                    }
                }



                cvSaveImage(rstimgfname, rstimg);

                return 0;
            }

                    }
    }
```

Comment: お使いのC++コンパイラの名前とバージョンやOSのバージョン、OpenCVのバージョンなど、環境の情報も分かる限りで良いので追記して頂けませんでしょうか？

Comment: 関数内部に `int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }` がありますが、コードのコピペをミスしていらっしゃいませんか……？

Comment: 中のプログラミングと、それから生じたエラーの修正、OS、コンパイラの追記致しました。よろしく願いいたします。

Comment: あおきさん、このご質問には +1 投票を受けている回答があるため、[ご自身だけでは削除できなくなっています](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2869/19110)。同じような問題で悩んだ方がこのページを見て解決できるかもしれないからです。同じ問題に同じ回答をつけなくて済むので、回答者の手間を減らす効果もあります。良い回答があるのに削除してしまうと、回答者の時間をある意味で無駄にしてしまうため、簡単には削除できないようになっています。今回はひとまず編集をロールバックしました。もし何か疑問点や要望がございましたら、[メタ サイト](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/)にご投稿頂ければ幸いです。お手数ですがよろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1):

> 以下のエラーが消えません！
>   cv::MAT h_image 式にはポインタ型が必要です

質問文中には記載がありませんが、下記コード `h_image->width` で発生しているエラーでしょうか？

```
cvRectangle(srcimg, cvPoint(0, 0),
            cvPoint(h_image->width, srcimg->height),
            CV_RGB(0xff, 0xff, 0xff), CV_FILLED);
```

変数`h_image`は`cv::Mat`クラス型ですから、エラーメッセージどおりポインタ型ではありません。「画像の幅」が必要であれば、`h_image.cols` または `h_image.size().width` と記述する必要があります。

---

題意とは無関係ですが、新旧OpenCVバージョンが混在したソースコードとなっているようです。特に `IplImage` 型は古いOpenCV 1.0時代の遺物のため推奨されません。基本的に `cv::Mat` の利用を検討してください（多くのOpenCV新機能は `IplImage` をサポートしません）

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます！cv::Mat に変えたところ、 cvLoadImage（）において、IplImageの値を利用して型cv::Matのエンティティを初期化することができない、cv::MatにメンバーimageDataがありません、などcv::Matに多数対応していないものが現れたのですが、どのように対応すればよいでしょうか？？プログラミング初心者で勉強不足です。すみません

Comment: 残念ながら `IplImage` から `cv::Mat` に単純置換すれば動くというものではありません。このアドバイスは「新たにコードを書く際に留意したほうがよい」程度に捉えてください。既存コードの変更にはそれなりのコストと理解度が必要になります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます、一度違う形で書き直したいと思います。ただ、色を認識しその色を四角形で囲む、というところまではいけました。これとは違う方針で、その描かれた四角形の重心（ｘｙ座標）を違う画面に表示しようとおもうのですが、どのようにしたらよいかわかりますか？？

Comment: C++とOpenCV全般について不慣れであれば、書籍等で学習されることをおススメします。もし中身を事前に確認できるなら、`IplImage`を使っている書籍は避けてください。（古い時期に書かれているか、著者の理解度が怪しいため）

Answer (score 0):

> - 識別子srcimgが定義されていません
> - 識別子"rstimg"が定義されていません
> - 識別子"rstimgfname"が定義されていません

この3つは、この名前の変数が定義されていないために生じているエラーです。これらの変数はプログラムの途中で使われていますが、それより前にその定義がなされていません。[編集前のコード](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/revisions/49973/6) では (変な所で main 関数の定義が始まっていることを除けば) これらの変数は定義されていますが、編集後の今はその部分が消されてしまっています。

Comment: ありがとうございます！単純に消してしまっていたようです！修正しました。ただ、もう一つのエラーがわかりません。。